# Docker image fails in CentOS but works on MacOS

Tags: python, docker, pip, containers

I'm using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos
RUN yum -y -q install epel-release && yum -y -q update && yum clean all \
&& yum -y -q install python-pip
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install -q pyvmomi==6.5.0.2017.5.post1
```

Not sure why it does work fine on MacOS using docker `17.09.0-ce` but it does not using CentOS with docker `17.11.0-ce-rc3`. There is an error in the pip installation, in this example I use `pyvmomi` but I have a similar error with other packages.

```
Step 3/3 : RUN pip install pyvmomi==6.5.0.2017.5.post1
 ---> Running in 49d94b300e7f
Collecting pyvmomi==6.5.0.2017.5.post1
  Downloading pyvmomi-6.5.0.2017.5-1.tar.gz (252kB)
Collecting requests>=2.3.0 (from pyvmomi==6.5.0.2017.5.post1)
  Downloading requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88kB)
Collecting six>=1.7.3 (from pyvmomi==6.5.0.2017.5.post1)
  Downloading six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=2.3.0->pyvmomi==6.5.0.2017.5.post1)
  Downloading certifi-2017.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (330kB)
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests>=2.3.0->pyvmomi==6.5.0.2017.5.post1)
  Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests>=2.3.0->pyvmomi==6.5.0.2017.5.post1)
  Downloading idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=2.3.0->pyvmomi==6.5.0.2017.5.post1)
  Downloading urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl (132kB)
Installing collected packages: certifi, chardet, idna, urllib3, requests, six, pyvmomi
  Found existing installation: chardet 2.2.1
    Uninstalling chardet-2.2.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 326, in run
    strip_file_prefix=options.strip_file_prefix,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 736, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 256, in rmtree
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 254, in rmtree
    os.rmdir(path)
OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/chardet'
```

Any idea why the same image fails to build across different operating systems? Also I tried this using ubuntu as the docker image and works perfect in both.
Thanks.

Comment: Are both using the same `centos` image? Use `docker images | grep centos` to verify they have the same hashes.

Comment: Have you considered just using a Python base image?

Comment: Always use a tag for your base image, preferably one that's not "latest".

Comment: This looks to be related to `pip` install `chardlet` not docker at all. For some reason the pip uninstall script is trying to `rmdir` a non-empty directory.

Comment: @kichik, yeah the image is exactly the same.
`docker images | grep d123f4e55e12`
`centos                                           latest              d123f4e55e12        12 days ago         197MB`

Comment: @cricket_007, it does work with Python image or with Ubuntu image, I was wondering why the same image does not work across different hosts.

Comment: Hi @jordanm, thanks for the advise, I had this problem with a completely different Dockerfile, I was trying to clean up everything else that could create notice to post the problem here. I tried this exact problem using `FROM centos:7.4.1708`, with the same result.

Comment: @stacksonstacks, I'm also looking in that direction but is weird that this works using the same pip configuration when the image is build in other host or using a different docker image, I have also noticed that if the packet can be installed with `yum`, for instance in this case `yum install python2-pyvmomi` it works well, but if the package is not available using yum, a pip installation works successfully.

Comment: @rogerscuall can you post the exact docker file youre using?

Comment: @stacksonstacks, is the one in my first message, I will put here again but I dont know how to format that correctly here.
`FROM centos`
`RUN yum -y -q install epel-release && yum -y -q update && yum clean all \`
`&& yum -y -q install python-pip`
`COPY requirements.txt /tmp/`
`RUN pip install -q pyvmomi==6.5.0.2017.5.post1`

Comment: Its a conflict between the `chardet` installed by `epel-release` http://mirror.xnet.co.nz/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/p/ and the one required by that specific version of `pyvmomi`. I'd stick with using the OS package i.e. `python2-pyvmomi`

Comment: @stacksonstacks, yeah, I think that is correct, I was using this a Dockerfile using 7 packages to install with pip, out of those 7 packages 4 are also available in the epel repo, if I take those out and use yum for those and pip for the rest the image gets built correctly. I would gladly mark your question as the correct answer although I still have the doubt why this works if the host is on MacOS or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by a conflict between the `chardet` package installed by `epel-release` 
see [epel package list](http://mirror.xnet.co.nz/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/p) and the one required by that specific version of `pyvmomi`.

Use the OS package version to avoid this conflict i.e. `yum -q install python2-pyvmomi`

The non-deterministic appearance of this error will be due to changes upstream in package verions in `epel-release` and those used in `pip install`